# Changing definition of FFT in Python

Tags: python, fft, ifft

The Fourier transform operations defined in Wikipedia are
[image]

which is analogous to the numerical algorithms in Python (and Matlab).

However I want to use this alternative definition:

[image]

in order to numerically show that the following equations are FT pairs:
[image]

My Python code is adapted from my previous question [Scaling problems with IFFT in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426377/scaling-problems-with-ifft-in-matlab). It performs FFT on `g(t)` and reverses the vector elements (code at bottom of post). Here is a plot of the analytical `G(w)` above compared to the fft solution and fft solution with the vector reversed.

[image]

It looks like there is agreement between the (reversed) numerical solution and `G(w)`, but there is actually a large difference between them. It's like there needs to be an additional shift along the horizontal axis in order to get a more accurate result:

[image]

There are similar issues when I use IFFT to go from `G(w)` to `g(t)`. So the question is, how do I implement this "alternative" definition of the FT? I'm not sure if my "vector reversal" method is appropriate. I suspect it has something to do with the phase of the FT.

### Edit:

In response to Cris Luengo, I have fixed the typos in the FT relations above. In addition, it seems possible to implement the "alternative" FT by applying a simple substitution to Wikipedia's FT definition:
[image]

Long story short, I should use `g(-t)` in the FFT in order to get `G(w)`. Does this sound logical? I tried this in my code and there is still a large discrepancy between the numerical and analytical result.

---

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft,fftshift,ifft,ifftshift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 3.119
b = 0.173

ts = 1e3 # time sampling
L = 500*ts # no. sample points
Ts = ts/L # sampling rate
Fs = 1/Ts # sampling frequency

f = (np.arange(-np.floor(L/2),(np.floor((L-1)/2)+1)))/L # digital (linear) freq
w = 2*np.pi*f # angular freq
t = np.arange(-L/2,L/2)*ts/L # time

H = lambda x:1*(x>0) # heaviside function

g = -1j*H(t)*np.exp(-(1j*a+b)*t) # test function for fft
Gn = 1/Fs*fftshift(fft(ifftshift(g))) # numerical fft
Gr = Gn[::-1] # reversed numerical result
Ga = 1/((Fs*w)-a+1j*b) # analytical

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(w,np.real(Gn),'.--',label='numeric')
plt.plot(w,np.real(Gr),'.--',label='numeric reversed')
plt.plot(w,np.real(Ga),label='analytic')
plt.xlabel('freq, w')
plt.title('real part of FFT')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlim((-.02,.02))
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(w,np.imag(Gn),'.--',label='numeric')
plt.plot(w,np.imag(Gr),'.--',label='numeric reversed')
plt.plot(w,np.imag(Ga),label='analytic')
plt.xlabel('freq, w')
plt.title('imag part of FFT')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlim((-.02,.02))

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(w,np.real(Gr-Gn),'.--',label='real')
plt.plot(w,np.imag(Gr-Gn),'.--',label='imag')
plt.xlabel(r'freq, $\omega$') 
plt.title(r'difference between FFT (reversed) and analytic') 
plt.legend()
plt.xlim((-.1,.1))

gn = Fs*ifftshift(ifft(fftshift(Ga))) # numerical ifft
gnr = gn[::-1] # reversed numerical result

plt.figure(3)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(t,np.real(gn),'.--',label='numeric')
plt.plot(t,np.real(gnr),'.--',label='numeric reversed')
plt.plot(t,np.real(g),label='analytic')
plt.xlabel('time, t')
plt.title('real part of IFFT')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlim((-1,1))
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(t,np.imag(gn),'.--',label='numeric')
plt.plot(t,np.imag(gnr),'.--',label='numeric reversed')
plt.plot(t,np.imag(g),'-',label='analytic')
plt.xlabel('time, t')
plt.title('imag part of IFFT')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlim((-1,1))

plt.figure(4)
plt.plot(t,np.real(gnr-g),'.--',label='real')
plt.plot(t,np.imag(gnr-g),'.--',label='imag')
plt.xlabel(r'time, t') 
plt.title(r'difference between IFFT (reversed) and analytic') 
plt.legend()
plt.xlim((-.1,.1))
```

Comment: Some thoughts: Those FT definitions miss a scaling. Python `fft` computes the DFT, not the FT; these are related but fundamentally different.  Your “alternate” FT simply reverses the forward and inverse transforms, meaning that there is more of a difference than just reversing the axis.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the advice! I have added more detail in my post.