# Applying Low Pass and Laplace of Gaussian Filter in Frequency Domain

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, convolution, dft

I am trying to applying these two filters in the frequency domain. First, the low-pass filter, followed by the Laplace of Gaussian filter.  Although my image is being filtered correctly, the output is wrapping around. Also, the output image is shifted ( it looks as if the image has been duplicated).

Here's the input and output:
[Before and After filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycw53.png)

Here's my code:

```
# Padding the image
image = Pad(image)

# The mask for low-pass filter
rows, cols = image.shape
center = (rows, cols)
crow, ccol = rows/2, cols/2
Low_mask = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=np.float32)
Low_mask[crow-cutoff:crow+cutoff, ccol-cutoff:ccol+cutoff] = 1

# Shifting the mask (low-pass)
Low_mask_dft = np.fft.fft2(Low_mask)
Low_mask_dft_shift  = np.fft.fftshift(Low_mask_dft)

# Shifting the image
image_dft = np.fft.fft2(image)
image_dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(image_dft)

# Performing the convolution
image_fdomain = np.multiply(image_dft_shift, Low_mask_dft_shift)

# Shifting the mask (LOG)
LOGmask = GaussKernel(center)
LOGmask_dft = np.fft.fft2(LOGmask)
LOGmask_dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(LOGmask_dft)

# Performing the convolution
frequency_image = np.multiply(image_fdomain, LOGmask_dft_shift)

# Now, return the image back to it's original form
result = np.fft.ifftshift(frequency_image)
result = np.fft.ifft2(result)
result = np.absolute(result)

return result
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Analytical Fourier transform vs FFT of functions in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317834/analytical-fourier-transform-vs-fft-of-functions-in-matlab)

Comment: The linked question is not identical, but it explains your problem: the FFT expects the origin of the image (and the kernel) in the top-left corner. Since you have it in the middle, it is shifted. This leads to the effects you are seeing. Use `ifftshift` on your kernel before `fft`.

Comment: Also, you don’t need to apply `fftshift` in the frequency domain unless you want to show it.

Comment: So, I took your advice and I used the ifftshift on the kernel before before applying the fft. However, I still obtained similar results. So, I removed the LOG filter from the operation and I generated a smooth image without wrap around. I'm guessing that the problem stems from using the LOG filter. Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is decide the boundary condition you're using.
The natural one for the Frequency Domain (For Discrete Data) is [Circular / Cyclic Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) which means circular boundary condition.

Once you set that and prepare data accordingly, everything works as required.

I created small MATLAB Script (You will be able to easily replicate it in Python) to show how it should be done.

The main thing is:

```
numRows = size(mI, 1);
numCols = size(mI, 2);

% Convolution in Spatial Domain
% Padding for Cyclic Convolution
mOGaussianRef = conv2(PadArrayCircular(mI, kernelRadius), mGaussianKernel, 'valid');
mOLogRef = conv2(PadArrayCircular(mI, kernelRadius), mLog, 'valid');

% Convolution in Frequency Domain
% Padding and centering of the Kernel
mGaussianKernel(numRows, numCols) = 0;
mGaussianKernel = circshift(mGaussianKernel, [-kernelRadius, -kernelRadius]);

mLog(numRows, numCols) = 0;
mLog = circshift(mLog, [-kernelRadius, -kernelRadius]);

mOGaussian  = ifft2(fft2(mI) .* fft2(mGaussianKernel), 'symmetric');
mOLog       = ifft2(fft2(mI) .* fft2(mLog), 'symmetric');

convErr = norm(mOGaussianRef(:) - mOGaussian(:), 'inf');
disp(['Gaussian Kernel - Cyclic Convolution Error (Infinity Norm) - ', num2str(convErr)]);

convErr = norm(mOLogRef(:) - mOLog(:), 'inf');
disp(['LoG Kernel - Convolution Error (Infinity Norm) - ', num2str(convErr)]);
```

Which results in:

```
Gaussian Kernel - Cyclic Convolution Error (Infinity Norm) - 3.4571e-06
LoG Kernel - Convolution Error (Infinity Norm) - 5.2154e-08
```

Namely it does what it should do.

The full code in my [Stack Overflow Q50614085 Github Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/StackOverflow/Q50614085).

If you want to see how it should be done for other Boundary Conditions (Or Linear Convolution), have a look at `FreqDomainConv.m`.