# MATLAB fft function of exponential multiplied by unit step thinks it's a constant

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to find the fourier transform of a filter `h(t)` that is `e^(-10*t)*u(t)` which I would expect to be equal to `H(f) = 1/(10+j*2*pi*f)` but I believe the `fft` function thinks it's a constant since I defined `t` to be a range in time. Thus it transforms it based off a constant. I can do it using `fourier` function and it will know symbolically the correct Fourier transform, but I just want to know if `fft` can do it as well?

`u(t)` is the unit step so I did

```
h = exp(-10*t)*heaviside(t) 
hfft = fft(x)/N
```

where `N` is the number of samples.

Comment: I expect Matlab has done exactly what you asked it to do. Take a look at the first related question and swap their choice of function for exp(-k*x) and you should then be heading in the right direction. [Comparing FFT of function to Analytical FT in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309758/comparing-fft-of-function-to-analytical-ft-solution-in-matlab?rq=2). Don't expect exact equality though since the FFT assumes periodic boundary conditions whereas the analytic solution is zeroes out to infinity. Getting an FFT to emulate a DFT accurately is something of an art.

Comment: @MartinBrown The FFT is an algorithm that computes the DFT. It produces the exact same values up to rounding error as computing the DFT sum directly. The DFT has a periodic boundary condition. I think you’re thinking of the Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT). That’s a different thing, not useful in computing because it is a continuous function.

Comment: Ellis, please post complete code. What is `t` when you defined `h`, and what is the `x` that goes into the `fft` call? See “[mre]”.